# Disable/Prevent CloudWatch Alarms when creating a new DynamoDB table with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have several non-scaling DynamoDB tables created via CloudFormation. Each table auto-creates CloudWatch Alarms (and more for each GSI). In PROD this is okay, but in DEV this adds up in terms of cost. For example, for `action` table with a GSI I get the following alarms created:

```
action-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm
action-WriteCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm
action-siteId-lastCaptured-index-ReadCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm
action-siteId-lastCaptured-index-WriteCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm
```

My CF template is quite simple for each table. For example:

```
tableuser:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  DependsOn: tablepage
  Properties:
    TableName: user
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
    PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
      PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits:
        Ref: 5
      WriteCapacityUnits:
        Ref: 5
```

How can I disable CloudWatch Alarms for CloudFormation-created DynamoDB tables? Of course I would prefer to do this via CloudFormation templates itself, but since I am not specifying their creation, I am not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose on-demand capacity (https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) instead of provisioned, no alarms will be created.

Instead of

```
ProvisionedThroughput:
  ReadCapacityUnits:
    Ref: 5
  WriteCapacityUnits:
    Ref: 5
```

You say

```
BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```